# Quote from Nietzsche on modernity and culture

Tags: nietzsche

I can't find a passage from one of Nietzsche's book (*Thus Spoke Zarathustra*?) about its opinion on modernity (the age he was contemporean of) and culture.

As far as I recall, the idea was that his contemporaries had a kind of mondane and passive approach to art, that they called "culture", which Nietzsche mocks.

For him, art should be experienced much more subjectively, and not be subsumed under a phenomenon called "culture".

Comment: Just go to the Gutenberg archive, & search to Nietzsche texts for the keyword.

Comment: unsurprisingly, that title does not include reference to modern, let alone modernity. neither can i (easily) find him using 'culture' as an unqualified slur. i would suggest editing the question to ask what nietzsche thought about modern culture, and you might get some replies. maybe even gordon

Comment: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1998/1998-h/1998-h.htm#link2H_4_0042

"Unto my children will I make amends for being the child of my fathers: and unto all the future—for THIS present-day!—

Thus spake Zarathustra." seems more concerned with thinness.

Comment: Nietzsche deals with culture most extensively in *Untimely Meditations*, might want to look there.

Answer (score 1):

Nietzsche thought modernity was synonymous with mediocrity, degeneration, and decline to such a deep and wide extent that its degeneration can be found in science and art, as well as in and on our bodies. There is no area of our existence that is unaffected by this contamination. Modernity is the era of a Life-destroying morality, where the the weakest and puniest people are preserved and made equal to the status of a great world historical conqueror like Julius Caesar or Napoleon. Modernity for him is the era of feminism, democracy, universalism, workers rights, and universal education. Nietzsche sees these as an assault upon the ancient order which drove the 'true' progress of civilization. So modernity, for Nietzsche is weakness, sickness, degeneration, and their triumph over an antiquity defined by cruelty, apartheid, caste systems, rank order, and universal slavery. His reaction to democratic movements, to enfranchisement, to equality, and especially to abolition of slavery form the context of his intervention into what he saw as the sorry state of European cultural production during his time. There can be no real cultural production without slavery, for Nietzsche. He had already by Zarathustra underlined the necessity of slavery in several texts.

Spring 1885-Autumn 1886, 2[13]

> …I believe that the great forwarding-driving and relentless democratic
> movement of Europe — that which calls itself 'progress' — and likewise
> even its preparation and moral prefiguration, Christianity — at bottom
> signifies only the tremendous instinctive overall conspiracy of the
> herd against all that is master, beast of prey, hermit and Caesar, in
> favor of the preservation and raising up of all the weak, oppressed,
> underprivileged, mediocre, semi-misfits, as a protracted slave
> rebellion against every kind of master, secretive at first then
> increasingly more self-conscious, ultimately against even the concept
> of 'master,' as a life and death war against every morality that
> springs from the womb and consciousness of a higher stronger masterful
> kind of human being — such a one requires slavery in some form and
> under some name as its foundation and condition. I believe, finally,
> that every enhancement so far in the type of human being was the work
> of an aristocratic society that believed in the long ladder of order
> or rank and value-difference between one person and another and
> required slavery.

p317, CW vol 16

Comment: Could you back some of the claims made in your answer with quotations?

Comment: Were you thinking of the chapter, On The Land of Culture

Comment: Not really, but your quote is very helpful anyway. I indeed read that Nietzsche was against democracy, but what about liberalism (= rule of law, low intervention of the government in the economy, separation of powers, separation of the State and Church, etc.)?

Comment: Your answer points that "Modernity for him is the era of feminism, democracy, universalism, workers rights, and universal education. " and that "Nietzsche sees these as an assault upon the ancient order which drove the 'true' progress of civilization.". But to me modernity is liberalism as defined above.

Comment: The quote you provided, along with your synthesis, just let me think that Nietzsche was against social democracy, not against modernity (= to me, classical liberalism)

Comment: And astonishingly, he jumps from one thing (social democracy) to another (brutal aristocracy), which are, apparently in Nietzche minds, opposite, but which to me are not. Classical liberalism is the real opposite of brutal aristocracy (or despotism), not social democracy.

Comment: Modernity is the era, the historical moment, of social democracy. socialism, equality, feminism, etc. This is why he identifies as being "untimely."

Comment: Many of Nietzsche's positions are consistent with liberalism, although he increasingly became more and more radical towards the end of his life. I see him as exhausting all of the political possibilities, in his effort to counter rising socialism, before arriving at 'aristocratic radicalism.' Nietzsche was unequivocally and unambiguously against democracy itself, and civil rights, and any extension or deepening of them, like socialism.

Comment: But liberalism is not against democracy (they just consider it is not the panacea), it is definitely for civil rights, and in sharp opposition to aristocracy!

Comment: Liberalism doesn't necessarily embrace democracy. And who is allowed to participate? There are kinds of liberalism that in fact limited who could participate in democracy, for example, the founders of the US were 'classical liberals' who created a democracy for the `plantation aristocracy` based on racialized, chattel slavery. The Greek polis was a democracy that was based on slavery.

Comment: "Liberalism doesn't necessarily embrace democracy." Sure, that's what I was saying. For being an "aristocratic radicalism" and against civil rights, Nietzsche is definitely not a classical liberal. Democracy is not central to classical liberalism